# I'm already in the USA since 2 weeks. Can I extend my stay by a month when I told the CBP I'd only be there for a month

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, international-travel, esta

I came here to the US to visit my girlfriend for a month. But now we wanna spend more time together, I want to reschedule my flight back home by a month, but I told the CBP when I arrived 2 weeks ago that I'd only stay for a month cause obviously I didn't know that one month wouldn't be enough. What do I do now.
I came here with ESTA by the way

Comment: @Julian What does your i-94 say about your length of admission https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/home?

Comment: What date were you given on the admission stamp?

Comment: @Traveller it says class of admission is WT and my admit until date is exactly what I told them. Does anyone know if I can get in contact with the CBP and request extending the stay?

Comment: @dunni weirdly I wasn't given a stamp at all it seems. I went through my passport and the only stamp i have is from when I visited the US last year

Comment: @Julian ‘WT’ denotes a person who has entered the US temporarily for tourism purposes under the Visa Waiver Program (it’s ‘WB’ for business purposes). You cannot apply to extend your stay if you entered under the VWP https://www.uscis.gov/visit-united-states/extend-your-stay

Comment: @Traveller isnt that just for the 90 days. i know i cant stay longer than 90 days at a time, no matter what. but I dont want to either, i just wanna extend my 30 days to 60

Comment: @Julian But you weren’t given a 90 day stay if, as you stated in your comment, your I-94 admit until date is ‘exactly what I told them’. Entry under the VWP is up to 90 days, as determined by the CBP Officer when you entered the US. It’s not a guaranteed 90 days fixed.

Comment: Why the downvote? This seems a perfectly reasonable and straightforward issue.

Comment: If you did not get a stamp, check your I-94 online at the link above.

Comment: @Traveller unless the regulations have changed, VWP visitors may only be admitted for less than 90 days if their passport expires before the 90 days are up (for six-month-club passports) or less than six months after the 90 days are up (for everyone else).

Comment: someone should just clearly and simply state the answer to the question, in an answer, instead of all these confusing comments

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: you cannot extend your stay.

Long answer: as @Traveller points out above, the "WT" on your passport denotes a person who has entered the US temporarily for travel purposes under the Visa Waiver Program. The [USCIS webepage cited in that Comment](https://www.uscis.gov/visit-united-states/extend-your-stay) is titled "Extend Your Stay," and contains the following text:

> **Extend Your Stay**
>
> ...
>
> If you want to extend your stay in the United States, you must file a request with U.S. Citizenship and Immigration Services (USCIS) on the Form I-539, Application to Extend/Change Nonimmigrant Status before your authorized stay expires. If you remain in the United States longer than authorized, you may be barred from returning and/or you may be removed (deported) from the United States. Check the date in the lower right-hand corner of your Form I-94, Arrival-Departure Record, to determine the date your authorized stay expires. We recommend that you apply to extend your stay at least 45 days before your authorized stay expires.
>
> You may apply to extend your stay if:
>
> - You were lawfully admitted into the United States with a nonimmigrant visa
> - Your nonimmigrant visa status remains valid
> - You have not committed any crimes that make you ineligible for a visa
> - You have not violated the conditions of your admission
> - Your passport is valid and will remain valid for the duration of your stay
>
> **You may not apply to extend your stay if you were admitted to the United States in the following categories:**
>
> - **Visa Waiver Program** *[emphasis added]*
> - Crew member (D nonimmigrant visa)
> - In transit through the United States (C nonimmigrant visa)
> - In transit through the United States without a visa (TWOV)
> - Fiancé of a U.S. citizen or dependent of a fiancé (K nonimmigrant visa)
> - Informant (and accompanying family) on terrorism or organized crime (S nonimmigrant visa)

Because you entered the US on the Visa Waiver Program, you are not eligible to extend your stay. You should depart the US no later than the "admit until" date. Not complyinig with the "admit until" date will make it immeasurably more difficult or impossible for you to enter the US in the future.

Comment: @Doc I don't agree, and think it does answer the question. The OP wants to stay longer than he told them he would. His "one month" statement at the border was accepted, and his I-94 admit until date was written for a term of one month. His VWP entry precludes extending his stay. What have I missed here?

Comment: And even if the OP could apply to extend his stay, the guidance says ‘we recommend you apply at least 45 days before your authorised stay expires’. The OP does not have enough time left to apply.

Comment: "What have I missed here?": the Code of Federal Regulations (or the statute, I don't remember which) doesn't actually allow discretion to shorten the 90-day admission period, so it's unlikely that OP was admitted for one month. The question doesn't actually say that the "I-94 admit until date was written for a term of one month" as far as I can see. On the other hand, this answer is carefully worded and does not imply that OP cannot stay for two months, so it is correct.  Presumably OP took a second look at the admit-until date, realized that all was well, and never came back to the question.

Comment: @Traveller someone who is eligible to extend but has waited until after the 45-day recommendation should nonetheless apply to extend before the end of their authorized stay because (1) if the extension is approved, it is retroactive so they won't have an adverse immigration history, (2) even if the extension is not approved their adverse immigration history won't be as bad as it would have been without applying (with respect to the automatic "unlawful presence" ban, at least).

Answer (score 0):

You can almost certainly extend your trip to the US, yes!

When you entered the country you would have been given a date that you must depart the country by.  This would normally be written into your passport over the entry stamp, but can also be accessed via the [CBP I94 website](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/) (select "Get most recent I94").

This will show an "Admit Until Date" which is the date that you must leave the country by.

With very few exceptions, when entering the US under the Visa Waiver Program (VWP) as you did, you will be given 90 days of admission to the US - even if you stated at time of entry that you were only staying a money.

You can change your return flight to be any time up until the day listed as the Admit Until Date without any consequences, and without any need to inform the US Government. As someone that entered under the VWP you can NOT extend your stay any longer than this date.

Comment: The OP comments that his  I-94 has the same date "that he told them," that is, a term of 30 days, not the 90 possible. And...a VWP entry makes the OP ineligible to extend whatever that date is.

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica I wonder if OP didn't misread a date in December as a date in October.  The CBP inspector's field manual (now rather old, granted) says "All 
VWP admissions are for 90 days unless the applicant’s passport is valid for a lesser period."